# Laravel 8 and Font Awesome

Tags: laravel, font-awesome

I just tried to install Font Awesome to a clean install of Laravel 8 following these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65812099/9145193

But I get these errors:

[image]

How can I fix these? Thanks!

Comment: Nobody knows a solution?

Comment: Also add mix.setPublicPath('public'); and mix.setResourceRoot('../'); https://gist.github.com/karlhillx/89368bfa6a447307cbffc59f4e10b621

Answer (score 0):

assume You put FontAwesome resource files at public directory

path:-**project_root_director/public/fontawesome/css/all.css**

then you wants to write like below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/fontawesome/css/all.css') }}">
```

Comment: As far as I know, I am not supposed to put resource files in the public directory.

Comment: @Masea you should not put php source code there and other sensitive stuff than should not be visible to the public. Fonts, css, js are ok.

Answer (score 0):

My app.scss file looks like this

```
// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

$fa-font-path:        "../webfonts";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular";
```

webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

require('laravel-mix-tailwind');
require('laravel-mix-purgecss');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').version()
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css').version()
    .copy(
        'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts',
        'public/webfonts'
    )
   .purgeCss()
  .tailwind('tailwind.config.js').version();
```

And in blade

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{mix('/css/app.css')}}">
<script defer src="{{mix('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

run `yarn dev` and done